# Regex Expression to remove certain characters from string expect at the start and end

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to remove all characters that are not space, tabs or alpha numeric from a string. Though if the character % exists and the start or end of the string they should be not be matched.

So far i have this

```
(?!<=^\%^)*[^\w\s](?<!%)
```

But it does not work as intented: https://regexr.com/5mckp

for example

```
%foo: bar [10]%
foo% bar%
foo%bar
```

should become

```
%foo bar 10%
foo bar%
foobar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this should work:

```
(?!^\%*)[^\w\s](?<!\%$)
```

Your error stands in the fact that the sequence `^\%^` will never occur since you are asking that the start of the sequence is after a % sign. Also the universal quantifier belongs to the % sign and not to the negative group. You should also check for the end of the line `$`. The rest was fine

Answer (score 0):

`[^\w\s]` does not match an underscore which is not alphanumeric, you need `[^\w\s]|_`.

Capture `%` at the start and end to keep them, use

```js
string.replace(/(^%|%$)|[^\w\s]|_/g, '$1')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/KKZTQx/1/). No lookbehind ensures the pattern work in Safari and other browsers not supporting lookbehind yet.

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const strings = ['%foo: bar___ [10]%','foo% bar%','foo%bar'];
strings.forEach( string => 
  console.log(string.replace(/(^%|%$)|[^\w\s]|_/g, '$1'))
)
```